# 2003 Jeep Liberty 3.7 v6 misfire

Tags: electrical, jeep, liberty

I have a misfire on all 3 cylinders 1, 3 & 5, all on the same side of motor. It seems more likely to be an electrical problem than coil packs since all are on same side. Is this a problem anyone has seen before? Maybe there is a shortcut to check power to coil packs? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

The coils have a 3 wire connector. Power Ground and signal. Check the power and ground with a test light. The best thing to do is to use a spark tester and pull each coil one at a time.

While this is a worst case scenario, i have seen a problem like this. The Jeep Liberty had snapped off the caps holding the camshaft in place, on one bank.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a bad O2 sensor it can cause a misfire as well. If you have a bad O2 sensor the computer can't get correct readings and because of this the computer goes into a reset cycle and not properly regulating what goes into the cylinder. I've seen this happen multiple times and also are you getting a check engine light?